# yq traverse complex values and convert to json file

Tags: yaml, jq, yq

I have a complex yaml and want to extract information from it using bash script.

The yaml is like:

```
content:
  images:
    sha256:4c8b96d4fffdfae29258d94a22ae4ad1fe36139d47288b8960d9958d1e63a9d0:
      annotations:
        kbld.carvel.dev/id: index.docker.io/dkalinin/k8s-simple-app
        kbld.carvel.dev/origins: |
          - resolved:
              tag: latest
              url: index.docker.io/dkalinin/k8s-simple-app
      image: image1
      imageType: Image
      layers:
      - digest: sha256:8ece9ac45f2b7228b2ed95e9f407b4f0dc2ac74f93c62ff1156f24c53042ba54
      origin: index.docker.io/dkalinin/k8s-simple-app@sha256:4c8b96d4fffdfae29258d94a22ae4ad1fe36139d47288b8960d9958d1e63a9d0
    sha256:4c8b96d4fffdfae29258d94a22ae4ad1fe36139d47288b8960d9958d1e63a9d1:
      annotations:
        kbld.carvel.dev/id: index.docker.io/dkalinin/k8s-simple-app
        kbld.carvel.dev/origins: |
          - resolved:
              tag: latest
              url: index.docker.io/dkalinin/k8s-simple-app
      image: image2
      imageType: Image
      layers:
      - digest: sha256:8ece9ac45f2b7228b2ed95e9f407b4f0dc2ac74f93c62ff1156f24c53042ba54
      - digest: sha256:8ece9ac45f2b7228b2ed95e9f407b4f0dc2ac74f93c62ff1156f24c53042ba5h
      - digest: sha256:8ece9ac45f2b7228b2ed95e9f407b4f0dc2ac74f93c62ff1156f24c53042ba6u
      origin: index.docker.io/dkalinin/k8s-simple-app@sha256:4c8b96d4fffdfae29258d94a22ae4ad1fe36139d47288b8960d9958d1e63a9d0
    sha256:4c8b96d4fffdfae29258d94a22ae4ad1fe36139d47288b8960d9958d1e63a9d2:
      annotations:
        kbld.carvel.dev/id: index.docker.io/dkalinin/k8s-simple-app
        kbld.carvel.dev/origins: |
          - resolved:
              tag: latest
              url: index.docker.io/dkalinin/k8s-simple-app
      image: image3
      imageType: Image
      layers:
      - digest: sha256:8ece9ac45f2b7228b2ed95e9f407b4f0dc2ac74f93c62ff1156f24c53042ba54
      origin: index.docker.io/dkalinin/k8s-simple-app@sha256:4c8b96d4fffdfae29258d94a22ae4ad1fe36139d47288b8960d9958d1e63a9d0
```

The expected result is:

```
{
"image1":
 ["8ece9ac45f2b7228b2ed95e9f407b4f0dc2ac74f93c62ff1156f24c53042ba54"], 
"image2": 
  ["8ece9ac45f2b7228b2ed95e9f407b4f0dc2ac74f93c62ff1156f24c53042ba54", 
   "8ece9ac45f2b7228b2ed95e9f407b4f0dc2ac74f93c62ff1156f24c53042ba5h", 
   "8ece9ac45f2b7228b2ed95e9f407b4f0dc2ac74f93c62ff1156f24c53042ba6u"], 
"image3": 
  ["8ece9ac45f2b7228b2ed95e9f407b4f0dc2ac74f93c62ff1156f24c53042ba54"]
}
```

The key `image1`, `image2`, `image3` are the `.content.images.image` value.

The value is the sha256 part of all digests in the Layers as a string list.

What I tried is to first get all keys using `images=$(yq -r '.content.images | keys' file)`
Then traverse the values using each key. But failed to traverse the values since the value is a complex one. Is there any simpler way to achieve this?

I'm using Go [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `with_entries` to modify each `.key` and `.value`. Or update each subitem `.[] |=` by modifying `key` and the context as value. Then, use `sub` with `""` in the second argument to remove substrings by regex:

```bash
yq -oj '.content.images | with_entries(
  .key = .value.image | .value |= [.layers[].digest | sub("^sha256:", "")]
)'

# or

yq -oj '.content.images | .[] |= (
  key = .image | [.layers[].digest | sub("^sha256:", "")]
)'
```

```json
{
  "image1": [
    "8ece9ac45f2b7228b2ed95e9f407b4f0dc2ac74f93c62ff1156f24c53042ba54"
  ],
  "image2": [
    "8ece9ac45f2b7228b2ed95e9f407b4f0dc2ac74f93c62ff1156f24c53042ba54",
    "8ece9ac45f2b7228b2ed95e9f407b4f0dc2ac74f93c62ff1156f24c53042ba5h",
    "8ece9ac45f2b7228b2ed95e9f407b4f0dc2ac74f93c62ff1156f24c53042ba6u"
  ],
  "image3": [
    "8ece9ac45f2b7228b2ed95e9f407b4f0dc2ac74f93c62ff1156f24c53042ba54"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Updated the question. It's better that the digests value can be directly in the list without the digest key.

Comment: @JoyceLee It'd be easier if you just provided the exact output you expect from this sample input. As far as I understand the change, replace `.layers` with `[.layers[].digest]`.

Comment: Thanks @pmf. Updated the question with sample output. The only missing part is I want to cut the digest without the `sha256:` prefix.

Comment: @JoyceLee Added `sub("^sha256:", "")` to remove `sha256:` from the strings.