# Delete an entry with the key matching regex using yq

Tags: yaml, yq

I have a json like this:

```
{
  "sha256key": [
    "438143050f234146300c44ed7e22be698e1e3c8c6bbc89b5c7e6276e8250a3a7"
  ],
  "validkey": [
    "77989d8d29d044112026eae94fe27e9df9ae29d9987d38bcdf470100175def76",
    "3c91a35a4e12eb89c8f25381f29438f270e9b0af1ef0cbcd416581cd7fe06a0e"
  ],
}
```

I want to remove all entries which have the key started with `sha256`

Expected result:

```
{
  "validkey": [
    "77989d8d29d044112026eae94fe27e9df9ae29d9987d38bcdf470100175def76",
    "3c91a35a4e12eb89c8f25381f29438f270e9b0af1ef0cbcd416581cd7fe06a0e"
  ],
}
```

I have tried

`yq 'del(select(.key | test("^sha256."))`  this does nothing

I'm using go [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq)

Comment: Re "this does nothing": Because `.key` addresses a key literally named key, but there is none (and if there was, the subsequent `test` would match against its value, not the key's name). In your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78077341/yq-traverse-complex-values-and-convert-to-json-file), `.key` was used inside `with_entries`, which temporarily converted each key-value pair into an "entries" object with two keys (accessible via `.key` and `.value`). For deleting certain entries, this is not necessary, as you can access keys more easily (see below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) allows you to use `*` for globbing:

```bash
yq -oj 'del(."sha256*")'
```

If you want to `test` by your regular expression, `select` by matching against the `key`:

```bash
yq -oj 'del(.[] | select(key | test("^sha256.")))'
```

Output:

```json
{
  "validkey": [
    "77989d8d29d044112026eae94fe27e9df9ae29d9987d38bcdf470100175def76",
    "3c91a35a4e12eb89c8f25381f29438f270e9b0af1ef0cbcd416581cd7fe06a0e"
  ]
}
```